# Delete Repository

Tags: git, github, repository, git-remote

I'm having a problem with git:

I created a repo on GitHub to push that repo so GitHub but because I did not research carefully, I deleted that repo on GitHub.

Then I created another repo and used git add but the error came up:

```
error: remote origin already exists.
```

I use `git remote -v` to review the list of urls and still have the old repo.

Then I use: **`git remote set-url <an-existing-remote-name> <url>`** to replace the new repo.
But I can't remember the remote name of the previous repo

So how can I delete / replace the old repo?

Comment: I don't quite understand the question. A *remote name* is a string like `origin`. The name `origin` is only special in that `git clone` *creates* it for you at the time you run `git clone`. Any simple alphabetic text string is allowed here: you make them up. The URL that goes with each remote is of course just a URL; you'll need to remember the correct URLs until you save them under some remote name.

Answer (score 0):

> Than I use: `git remote set-url` to replace the new repo.
> But I can't remember the remote name of the previous repo

You don't have to: use `origin`: that will *override* the previous origin URL

```
git remote set-url origin https://github.com/<me>/MyNewRepository
```

Then you can start pushing to your new repository.